# Complex book suggestions

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, reference-request, complex-numbers, book-recommendation

I take complex analysis course. And my instructor use -Bak and Newman's complex analysis book, Springer. This book explains complex analysis too rapidly and superficially. Please give me book suggestions which are the same as the above book in terms of content but with more clarity.

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

You might like Marsden and Hoffman's "Basic Complex Analysis". There's also Silverman's "Introductory Complex Analysis" which has the advantage of being very inexpensive (it's a Dover reprint).

You might also find that what you need is not a "better" explanation, but just a different one. If you read two or three authors' exposition and proof of a theorem, you will undoubtedly have a more complete understanding of the concept.

Comment: +1 for the excellent advice *You might also find that what you need is not a "better" explanation, but just a different one*.

Comment: Okay thank you for suggestions. I Will look at these book:)@BaronVT

Answer (score 1):

The best book I have used to study the topic is Ahlfors' book. I recently used Lang,  which presents a very easy to read treatment of the topic, but I didn't feel it covered the material as deeply as Ahlfors.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the best book to give a very clear and yet rigorous of the material for a basic CA course is Flanigan's "Complex Variables."

The text is very readable and contains a great number of pictures to enhance understanding.

As a plus it is a Dover edition, so it is very affordable.

[http://www.amazon.com/Complex-Variables-Dover-Books-Mathematics/dp/0486613887](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486613887)